# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'column_name' in 'field list' - mappings in entity are the same in as database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping

I receive the error as in the title for column "accepted_at",however i cannot see where i am making a mistake because i checked the names of the columns and the entities seem to be anotated properly.Lombok is used so don't wonder why there are no setter and getters

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private Long version;

@Column(name = "accepted_at")
private Date acceptedAt;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "accepted_by_id")
private Account acceptedBy;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "token_id")
private Token token;

@Column(name = "date_created")
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name = "is_accepted")
private Boolean isAccepted;

@Column(name = "is_enabled")
private Boolean isEnabled;

@Column(name = "last_updated")
private Date lastUpdated;

@Column(name = "organization_id")
private String organizationId;

@Column(name = "pending_status")
private int pendingStatus;

@Column(name = "pending_status_date")
private Date pendingStatusDate;

@Column(name = "profile_type")
private int profileType;

@Column(name = "valid_from")
private Date validFrom;

@Column(name = "valid_to")
private Date validTo;
```

Here is how i create the table for profile via a script.

```
create table profile
(
id                   bigint(20) not null auto_increment,
version              bigint(20) not null,
accepted_at          datetime,
accepted_by_id       bigint(20),
account_id           bigint(20) not null,
token_id             bigint(20),
date_created         datetime,
is_accepted          bit(1) not null,
is_enabled           bit(1) not null,
last_updated         datetime,
organization_id      national varchar(10) not null,
pending_status       int(11),
pending_status_date  datetime,
profile_type         int(11) not null,
valid_from           datetime,
valid_to             datetime,
primary key (id),
key organization_id (organization_id)
);
```

I am using application.yml instead of application.properites. I hope this is usefull somehow

```
 spring:
  datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/*****?serverTimezone=GMT
   username: root
   password: ******
  jpa:
   open-in-view: false
 flyway:
  enabled: true
 thymeleaf:
  suffix: .html
  cache: false
```

Comment: Can you upload your application.properties file for DB configuration ? Because, if you have not used  property : spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl - then, it will create fields name automatically based on your entity variables. So if you want to explicitly use these fields, then add above property.

Comment: Hello! Yes i have updated the question. I am not using what you just described.

Comment: I have never used annotation for version i don't know how it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

please replace your yml properties with below :

```
spring:
  datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/focus3?serverTimezone=GMT
   username: root
   password: 123456
  jpa:
   open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
    naming:
      physical-strategy : org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
 flyway:
  enabled: true
 thymeleaf:
  suffix: .html
  cache: false
```

because, your yml properties should like below to use your fields name,

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: I have tried that but now it seems to be messing with my spring security and cannot authenticate the users login

Comment: Please check after adding driver class, hibernate dialect properties/

Comment: Hi @Alex, Also, try to give begin space at naming properties after hibernate hierarchy as naming is a sub-property.

Comment: Thank you for the information,sadly the problem seems to be something else :(